# Not able to bind setInterval inside for loop

Tags: javascript

I am trying to execute a setInterval inside a for-loop , but instead of executing in interval it is executing at once.

In this example I tried with `.bind()`

```
var bck =['red','yellow'];
for(var i = 0;i<bck.length;i++){
   var num = i;
   console.log(num)
     setInterval(function() {
        $('.demoDiv').css('background',bck[num]);
        }.bind(num), 5000);
}
```

I also tried by creating a closure.

```
for(var i = 0;i<bck.length;i++){
   (function(i) {
     var _set=   setInterval(function(){
        $('.demoDiv').css('background',bck[i]);
        }, 5000)
    }(i));
}
```

Here is a [**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/2nwk0mkb/2/)

Comment: You're creating all the intervals at once (well, close enough), so they will all execute at nearly the same time 5 seconds later.

Comment: The full content of your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. A fiddle is fine provided the content is also **here**. But preferably, use Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) for a runnable [mcve].

Comment: I bet you really don't want `setInterval` here at all, you probably want `setTiemout`.

Comment: Understood what you meant

Answer (score 1):

Why you hardcoding ? you dont need to use a loop, just the <kbd>[setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)</kbd> will do the trick

```js
var bck = ['red', 'yellow'];
var i = 0;
setInterval(function() {
  $('.demoDiv').css('background', bck[i%2]);
  i++;
}, 5000)
```

```css
.demoDiv {
  background: rebeccapurple;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="demoDiv">

</div>
```

**Edit:** Imporved by @Akshay Khandelwal, use modulus instead of if statemant.

Comment: you could use modulus instead

Comment: My main objective is to understand the working of setInterval/setTimeout inside loop.

Comment: @user2181397: If that's your main objective, you'll want to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example The question would be a duplicate of that if it weren't for the timing aspect.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reseting `i` which is apparently a good idea, i chose to use a mathematical operation to achieve the same

```
var bck =['red','yellow'];
var i =0;
var _set=   setInterval(function(c) {
        $('.demoDiv').css('background',bck[i%2]); // Check the modulus value;
    i++;
}, 5000)
```

Comment: additional line of if condition in below answer removed.

Comment: Well I know it , but my main objective is to understand the working of setInterval/setTimeout inside loop.

Comment: in your code, what really happened is different intervals [2 in number] got set to execute after every 5 seconds which you did not expect. Something that you did not anticipate is that the for loop would end up immediately and have 2 different setintervals execute the interval almost consecutively without any delay.

Comment: This tricked you in believing that only one interval is being executed.

Comment: if you had not done `var _set` and use `_set` directly instead that would override the previous interval leading to execution of just one interval again, which you'd excpect.

Comment: can you create a working jsfiddle with setInterval inside for loop

Comment: I guess, no! That wont help unless your objective is to get the variable (i) inside the function there's no reason why you should use **for** and **closure** together. and no reason at all to use **setinterval** and **for** together in any situation.